# How can I replicate this video style?

Tags: 3d, modeling, blender

I want to make videos in blender like @henchman.1 or @bug.sex (those are their instagrams). They say that they use blender, but I don't have an idea on how to make the videos so grainy and simple. I love how simple they are and it almost looks like a kid made it and I love it. If you can help me out or give me a basic layout idea, let me know.

examples:

https://www.instagram.com/p/B_6CpT7jn-t/

https://www.instagram.com/p/B2Hd8iYFkCh/

https://www.instagram.com/p/B1wYsrQl1AS/

https://www.instagram.com/p/B472BPaF1-i/

Comment: Welcome Pacer, are you expecting users to go hunting for some obscure video somewhere? It may be best to include links to any references you use. (And all caps is a bad thing, I removed that aspect of the title).

Comment: Post links or screen grabs so we know what you mean, please - I’m one who’s likely to be an answerer, but I neither have an Instagram account nor am going to search those usernames...

Comment: After your question edit I see there is no grain in these. It's pixelization. Perhaps just low res video scaled up so the pixels are visible.  Since these are instagram users, you could ask them.

Comment: Also if you need help in Blender, there is a [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) where such questions might be better suited.

Answer (score 1):

These are obviously well done simple 3D animations. The "graininess", as you say (see NOTE1), is intentional, it's not caused by missing knowledge. It can be aimed to create a mood or it can be done to save space or computing time. It can be got by reducing model complexity, rendering accuracy or pixel resolution or all of them mixed. If kids made these from the start, they must be quite skilled kids. It needs something more than good will to generate 3D models, to make them to move or at least the camera to move and to insert, maybe even to create some music which fits.

Some ability to work with 3D models and animated videos is still needed if the 3D models are downloaded from an external source (there are numerous free and commercial).

It is, of course, possible that some of these are compiled and post-processed from captured video game scenes. Even it needs some skills.

How to make one:

Get a 3D program, a screen video recorder and a multitrack video editing program which accepts your screen recordings as source clips. The 3D program can be for ex. SketchUP. Download from its Warehouse a free 3D model of some object or more complex scene.

Make numerous screen recordings where you pan, rotate and zoom the 3D scene or make the camera to fly around.

Draw some simple images which have transparent background so that the images can float in the video.

Get an "easy music builder" which contains thousands of ready to use rhythmic and melodic phrases + noises + simple enough combining frame to create easily some modern music. Magix Music Maker is a good example.

In video editor try to combine your screen recordings and drawings so that you can insert some music, too. You can insert some pan and zooming effects also in the video editor for more complexity. The whole video effect repertoire can be used for the same.

If you want to make some advanded looking with static non-moving objects you can try simultaneous camera moving and zooming for apparent object movements. In reality only the perspective changes but some object seems to become closer or go further when some other seems to stay in its place.

If you are not musical, insert weird noises like the maker of the wireframe street flight video has done. I guess some planning pays off. I guess it's avoided in the wireframe street flight video.

Finally render the video. Use low pixel resolution to get the wanted "graininess".

NOTE1: Term "grain" is reserved for certain type of noise in photos and software effects which simulate it. An extreme example: https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/en/view-image.php?image=276395&picture=grainy-image-of-a-shadow That kind of grain does not exist in your video examples.

Comment: There's no "graininess" in the OPs examples.  It's just pixelization. Grain is an entirely different thing.

Comment: The questioner calls it grain. I guess he doesn't know the term is already reserved for certain type of random noise.

Comment: I realise that, but perhaps you should mention it in your answer.

Comment: i dont know the i looked at the first one. Looks like a good first 3D project to me. Though to be honest its really hard to be that bad quality with principled shaders these days.

Comment: thank you for this. I know these people definitely understand the programs they use to a good extent, but the strangeness and simplicity of the videos are what intrigues me although i know they aren't simple to make

Comment: @pacerdigital no they are simple to make, they would have been simple to make in 1990's too. Its just that you have absolutely no basis on 3D graphics. Getting you to understand concepts of 3d software is going to take longer than any of the animations you linked. So one you know how to do basic operations you should be able to do all of the examples in a few hours. The second to last one being hardest to make.

Comment: @joojaa thanks, i understand some basic blender stuff but not enough. any links on where I could go to learn more? like any specific youtubers or something?